# Is there a way to map multiple fields into one single property?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to use Doctrine with a poorly designed PostgreSQL database. Some tables have DATE and TIME fields that should be TIMESTAMP fields.

Is it possible map a pair of DATE and TIME fields into a DateTime property on my classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a method `getTimestamp()` that would return a `new \DateTime($this->getDate()-­>format('Y-m-d') . ' ' . $this->getTime()->format('H:i:s'))` object and create a `setTimestamp(\DateTime $date)` method that would set the two values by get date and time separatly.

```
public function setDate(\DateTime $date)
{
    $this->date = $date;
}

public function getTime()
{
    return $date;
}

public function setTime(\DateTime $date)
{
    $this->date = $date;
}

public function getTime()
{
    return $date;
}

public function getTimeStamp() {
    return new \DateTime($this-­­>getDate()-­>format('Y-m-d') . ' ' . $this->getTime()->format('H:i:s'));
}

public function setTimeStamp(\DateTime $timestamp) {
    $this->setDate(new \DateTime($timestamp->format('Y-m-d'));
    $this->setTime(new \DateTime($timestamp->format('H:i:s'));
}
```

or something like that. You can then exclusively use the `get/setTimestamp()` in your code.

**DQL**

You pass your timestamp as a single param and you bind 2 params like this :

```
public function getSomething(\DateTime $timestamp, $someparam) {

    $dql = "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE date = :date AND time = :time"

    // Create query and params binding
    // param('date', $timestamp-­>format('Y-m-d'));
    // param('time', $timestamp-­>format('H:i:s'));

    return $result;

}
```

You might have to wrap your params values in a `new \DateTime()` since doctrine needs a DateTime instance as date, time and timestamp.

This give you a simple interface to support in your code, but allow to make abstraction of the database schema.

Comment: Great solution, but how my DQL queries should be written?

Answer (score 0):

You also could create a view, in which those fields are combined into one. Then from your model classes use the view instead of the real tables.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but the need to deal with view rules for upserts looks more complicated than a pure PHP solution.